# Angular package error : TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: asp.net, angular

I tried to update the angular version and add some packages but I got that error which is mentioned below and I also shared my "package.json.I tried these:

1. delete "wwwroot\dist" folder and recompiling it. I got the same result
2. delete "node_modules" folder and run "npm install".I got the same result
3. running webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js webpack . I got same result.

Any solution?

Packages :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.0",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^3.0.3",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "es6-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.11",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "preboot": "5.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.4",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.9.0-rc.0",
    "@types/chai": "^4.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.6.2",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "karma": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.5"
  }
```

Error :

```
NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>) at __extends (D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:22814:5) at D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:22832:5 at D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:22861:2 at Object.setPrototypeOf.__proto__ (D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:22788:10) at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:22791:2) at __webpack_require__ (D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30) at Object.setPrototypeOf.__proto__ (D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:5090:204) at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:5093:2) at __webpack_require__ (D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30) Current directory is: D:\Projects\CH.AdminClient\CH.AdminClient
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance+<InvokeExportAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance+<InvokeExportAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl+<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl+<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Prerendering.PrerenderTagHelper+<ProcessAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner+<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
AspNetCore._Views_Home_Index_cshtml+<ExecuteAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in Index.cshtml
+
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server" asp-prerender-data='new {
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+<RenderPageCoreAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+<RenderPageAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+<RenderAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor+<ExecuteAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor+<ExecuteAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult+<ExecuteResultAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeResultAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```